# Add a join in a UNION query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query with union all in mysql:

```
SELECT id_Event, pushToken, '' as phone, name, surname1 ai, surname2, NIF, year, city, status FROM signedup WHERE status = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT id_Event,'' as pushToken,  phone, name, surname1 ai, surname2, NIF, year, city, status FROM signedupLocal WHERE status = 0
ORDER BY ai ASC
```

Now, I created a new table (tableX) with some fields I want to add to each row. This new table has these fields:

```
id, id_Event, NIF, as1,as2,as3,as4
```

I want that each row in the first query get 4 new fiels (as1,as2,as3,as4), each one in the correct row. id_Event and NIF must match.

I guess I should add a join in each query but I am not sure how it will work.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: What don't you understand? I will try to explain. I want to add some fields in other table to my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, JOIN will be used. Wrap the UNION result into a table alias and then join with TableX. Try this:

```
SELECT as1,as2,as3,as4,y.id_Event, pushToken, phone, name, ai, surname2, y.NIF, year, city, status
FROM tableX
JOIN (
   SELECT id_Event, pushToken, '' as phone, name, surname1 ai, surname2, NIF, year, city, status 
   FROM signedup WHERE status = 0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id_Event,'' as pushToken,  phone, name, surname1 ai, surname2, NIF, year, city, status 
   FROM signedupLocal WHERE status = 0
) y
ON tableX.id_Event = y.id_Event AND tableX.NIF = y.NIF
ORDER BY ai ASC
```

Comment: It is perfect, just one minus mistake. Because I changed the name of surname1 in the first query, you don't need to put surname1 ai in the new one. It gives you an error. Just ai is enough. Anyway, it works like a charm. Thanks man, I didn't know how to do this.

Comment: Other thing I am not sure. I have 2 fields, pushToken and phone, which one exists in first query and other one in second. You set '' phone in the first SELECT. should it be just "phone"? I think so.

Comment: Last comment was for @Aziz Shaikh

Comment: @Biribu fixed it in the query above, please try now.

Comment: Great. Then it was like I said. I just removed it. Thanks again.